# YouTube API: Get full playlist

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to understand recursion :) Well, specifically fetching a full YouTube playlist using Google's PHP Client Library.

This is my function in my class called YTFunctions. It first gets called with a valid, authenticated YouTube_Service object and a playlistId. Then, it should theoretically call itself over and over again as long as the PlaylistItems response has a nextPageToken and then append that to its outputs which should contain all objects (videos) contained in the playlist. For some reason, it just return an empty array.

```
public static function getFullPlaylistByID($youtube, $playlistId, $pageToken) {
    $params = array(
        'maxResults' => 50,
        'playlistId' => $playlistId,
    );
    if ($pageToken !== false) {
        $params['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
    }
    $playlistResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet,contentDetails', $params);
    error_log(count($playlistResponse['items']));
    $playlistItems = $playlistResponse['items'];
    if (isset($playlistResponse['nextPageToken'])) {
        $playlistItems = array_merge($playlistItems, YTFunctions::getFullPlaylistByID($youtube,$playlistId, $playlistResponse['nextPageToken']));
    } else {
    }
    return $playlistItems;
}
```

I am clearly missing something here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Tobias Timpe

Answer (score 1):

here my class that will get all playlistItems

```
<?php
class yt{
    public $DEVELOPER_KEY = '{DEVELOPER_KEY}';
    public $client;
    public $youtube;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->client = new Google_Client();
        $this->client->setDeveloperKey($this->DEVELOPER_KEY);
        $this->youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($this->client);      
    }

    public function getPlaylistItems($playlist, $maxResults, $nextPageToken = ''){
        $params = array(
            'playlistId' => $playlist,
            'maxResults' => $maxResults,
        );

        // if $nextPageToken exist
        if(!empty($nextPageToken)){
            //insert $nextPageToken value into $params['pageToken'] 
            $params['pageToken'] = $nextPageToken;
        }

        $youtubeFeed = $this->youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('id,snippet,contentDetails', $params);
        // function for looping our feed and entry
        $this->setFeed($youtubeFeed);

        //check if nextPageToken are exist 
        if(!empty($youtubeFeed['nextPageToken'])){
            $insert = $this->getPlaylistItems($playlist, $maxResults, $youtubeFeed['nextPageToken']);
            // return to function if nextPageToken are exist
            return $insert;
        }

    }
}

$yt = new yt();

?>
```

and than use our class

```
$yt->getPlaylistItems('PL0823049820348','25');
```